# How do I split a string into two strings using a comma, and store the strings? (C++)

Tags: c++

I looked to see if this had been asked before, but all I got was answers for Java. I have to read first names and last names from a file, in the format of (lastname,firstname). The program requires us to (among other things), display the name in the format of (firstname lastname), with a space instead of a comma. I figured the easiest thing to do would be to split the string into two smaller strings, and then just display them in order. How would I go about doing this? I saw some BOOST token thing, but I can't use that as the program has to be able to run on vanilla CodeBlocks.

Comment: You can use `[tagName]` to filter results by tag. There are some good splitting solutions in a question near the top of the FAQ/votes list for C++ as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 9):

Certainly more compact, if not more elegant solutions are possible, but this does it--

```
#include <string>

//... read input_str from the file

int pos = input_str.find_first_of(',');
std::string firstname = input_str.substr(pos+1),
      lastname = input_str.substr(0, pos);

std::string output_str = firstname + " " + lastname;
```